# Unable to restore 2016 MacBook Pro

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, restore

I am trying to restore the OS on a MacBook Pro (2016, touchbar). I've looked at all the answers I can find on here but none seem to address my issue.

I erased the disk but the restore process isn't working and I may have tried to erase the disk again via Disk Util in Recovery (this was a few months ago and I don't remember everything I did).

The first thing that comes up when I turn it on is a folder with a question mark:
[image: startup screen with question mark folder]

When I boot into Internet recovery and select Reinstall macOS I get an error
[image]

The disks look like the following:
[image: physical volume]
[image: partition]
[image: osx base image]

Apologies for all the photos of my screen but thanks for any help.

Comment: Try installing the latest version compatible with your Mac. Press `Opt-Cmd-R` while booting.  What solutions did you attempt?  It’s important to share this info so we don’t duplicate efforts and we have a clearer picture of your issue.

Comment: @Allan, that was exactly what I needed - thank you.